# Do we have RowError for linq just like DataTable has one?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, linq

how do I notify the user about the problem occurring when updating rows, using linq SubmitChanges(), like this:

[image: RowError]

previously, I used a `DataTable` and `SqlDataAdapter`, to display about the stock status from the MSSQL database which throws up upon `SqlDataAdapter.Update()`
Now want to move to linq due to its high speed retrieval of master-detail data

Comment: As an alternative you can implement `IDataErrorInfo` interface for your models.

Comment: the error message comes from the database upon `SubmitChanges()`, how do I implement using `IDataErrorInfo `